# Logout Link is not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using **JSF** and **Primefaces** in my web application.

In this i am using one form which includes some some details to be filled by student.
So there is some validation on that fields

And, On this page there are two button one is Submit and Other is Logout

When I pressed submit button form is displaying validation error if details are not completed.

But Same things also shown while pressing LOGOUT link also

Logout is p:commadLink

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="logout" type="submit"  action="#{userManagedBean.logout}">
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/logout.png"></p:graphicImage>
     </p:commandLink>
```

Submit is h:commandButton

```
<h:commandButton image="/images/submit_button.png" type="submit" action="#{referManagedBean.saveDetails}" value="submit"></h:commandButton>
```

I need Logout link skip this validation step and directly goes to managed bean called function.

**How can i skip Validation Step ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem i used **immediate="true"** by which it skips the validation phase.

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="logout" type="submit" immediate="true"  action="#{userManagedBean.logout}">
     <p:graphicImage value="/images/logout.png"></p:graphicImage>
     </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the log-out action seems that has nothing to do with the details form (being validated), you could just move the button to different form (h:form) so it wouldn't trigger the details form validation anyway.